# CPU bit, its cache line, the bus between memory and CPU, and its registers?

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-hardware

Should the size of its cache line, the width of bus between memory and CPU, and the size of its registers be all equal to the CPU bit?

Is CPU bit determined by the size of its cache line, the width of bus between memory and CPU, or the size of its registers, something else?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an answer over on stack-overflow that is better than any I could write: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434606/how-do-we-determine-if-a-processor-is-8-bit-16-bit-or-32-bit

Comment: My questions are not answered there.

Answer (score 3):

The nominal bit width is typically the size of the general purpose registers (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434606/how-do-we-determine-if-a-processor-is-8-bit-16-bit-or-32-bit) pointed to in [Wandering Logic's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/7459/wandering-logic) [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21331/cpu-bit-its-cache-line-the-bus-between-memory-and-cpu-and-its-registers#comment-41636) for some of the details), so the width of *general purpose* registers would typically equal the nominal bit width.  However, other internal storage might use a different size. (Perhaps the most common modern examples would be 32-bit processors with 64-bit floating-point registers and many architectures with 128-bit or larger SIMD registers.)

The size of a cache line is typically four or more times larger than the size of general purpose registers in order to reduce tag overhead, to exploit spatial locality, and to exploit higher burst bandwidth (even communicating with an on-chip L2 cache has per-request overhead, since the days of fast page DRAM [and possibly before] burst accesses have provided more bandwidth than random access).

(A processor with multiple levels of cache may choose different line sizes for the different levels. Having a smaller L1 cache line size increases the number of cache lines; when combined with prefetching this can reduce the number of cache misses by reducing internal fragmentation [where only part of the cache line will be used while it is resident]. With on-chip interfaces, the access overhead is lower [on-chip wires are "cheaper" and lower latency means less buffering], so smaller L1 cache lines are not as expensive as for a last level cache. An instruction cache may also choose to use a different line size than a data cache since code often has greater spatial locality.)

The width of a memory interface is often tied to the size of cache lines in the last level cache and the efficient burst length of the memory. E.g., a 64-bit DDR3 memory interface is suitable for 64-byte last level cache lines (DDR3 uses a burst length of 8). This makes efficient use of memory bandwidth. However, using a narrower interface may be attractive in some embedded systems where cost and power are more important than performance and using a wider interface may be attractive in some systems to increase per-access bandwidth or to support DRAM chip redundancy (with mechanisms like ChipKill) with commodity DRAMs which have limited width choice.

Since the width of memory modules is standardized and cache line sizes are not, cache lines have more flexibility in terms of size. It is not unusual for the line size of a last level cache to be twice the size of a single burst access to a standard memory module.

Note that this applies to a single memory interface with an on-chip memory controller and no buffer chips (like FB-DIMM and Intel's Scalable Memory Buffer). The width of an interface to an off-chip memory controller or buffer chip is less tied to DRAM behavior. With a buffer chip, the interface is usually narrower to reduce the cost of having more connections (pins or solder balls) on the processor. Since such interfaces are specialized, their width is more driven by the electrical characteristics of the connection and less by DRAM characteristics or cache line size.

Also note, that a single processor chip can have multiple memory interfaces. These interfaces can also be bound together to provide greater per-access bandwidth (which may be attractive if last level cache lines are larger than a burst from a single interface).